# how to show only 1 submit button in form with many foreach

Tags: php, html, forms, laravel

Currently i have a form and calling a few data using foreach's like below:

```html
@foreach($db as $intentName => $questionAnswer)

<div class="form-group edit-response-container">
  <label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{{$number}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{$number}}"> {{$intentName}} <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></label>
  <div class="collapse" id="collapse-{{$number}}">
    <div class="well">

      <form action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@savedmb', [$companyID, $entityType])}}" method="post">
        {{csrf_field()}}
        <div class="col-md-12 btn-toolbar">
          <button type="button" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right add-new">Add Answer</button>
          <button type="submit" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right">Save</button>
        </div>

        @foreach($questionAnswer['q1'] as $question => $questionID)
        <table class="question">
          <tr>
            <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
            <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
          </tr>
        </table>
        @endforeach

        @foreach($questionAnswer['q2'] as $question => $questionID)
        <table class="question">
          <tr>
            <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
            <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
          </tr>
        </table>
        @endforeach

        @foreach($questionAnswer['q3'] as $question => $questionID)
        <table class="question">
          <tr>
            <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
            <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
            <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
          </tr>
        </table>
        @endforeach

        @foreach($questionAnswer['intent'] as $intent => $intent)
        <input type="hidden" name="intent" value="{{$intent}}">
        @endforeach

        <input type="hidden" name="entityValue" value="{{$q}}" readonly/>

        <br><br>

        <div class="new-field">
          <table class="response">
            <tr>
              <td class="labels"><p>Answer:</p></td>
              <td><input type="text" name="newAnswer[]" value=""></td>
            </tr>
          </table>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<?php
  $number++;
?>

@endforeach
```

so the function is all working fine but im having one problem as you can see from the picture below the form is the same but currently the button is showing me on each foreach if im not mistaken but i only want to have ONE submit and ONE add button and not on all foreach. How can i do that?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/el4gi.jpg)

my controller as below:

```html
public function savedmb(Request $request, $companyID, $entityType)
{
  $a = count($request->question);
  for ($p=0; $p < $a; $p++) { 

  $nq = new DiraQuestion;
  $nq->intent = strtolower($request->intent);
  $nq->eType = $entityType;
  $nq->eVal = strtolower($request->entityValue);
  //$nq->synonym = strtolower($request->syn);
  $nq->queries = $request->question[$p]; 
  $nq->company_id = $companyID;
  $nq->save();

  }


  $x = count($request->newAnswer);
  for ($i=0; $i < $x; $i++) { 

  $nr = new DiraResponses;
  $nr->intent = strtolower($request->intent);
  $nr->eType = $entityType;
  $nr->eVal = strtolower($request->entityValue);
  $nr->reply = strtolower($request->newAnswer[$i]);
  $nr->company_id = $companyID;
  $nr->save();

  }

  return back();
}
```

and my route:

```html
Route::post('savedmb/{companyID}/{entityType}','Chatbot\ChatbotController@savedmb');
```

Comment: Well no matter what, that foreach loop that wraps the entire HTML is going to print out x many times based on how many iterations it does.  So you can't do anything short of an ugly Javascript fix unless you remove the buttons from between the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place your button `out of` loop:

```
<div class="form-group edit-response-container">
<label data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse-{{$number}}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{$number}}"> {{$intentName}} <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></label>
<div class="collapse" id="collapse-{{$number}}">
<div class="well">

  <form action="{{action('AltHr\Chatbot\ChatbotController@savedmb', [$companyID, $entityType])}}" method="post">
    {{csrf_field()}}
    <div class="col-md-12 btn-toolbar">
      <button type="button" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right add-new">Add Answer</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn alt-btn alt-btn-green pull-right">Save</button>
    </div>
@foreach($db as $intentName => $questionAnswer)
    @foreach($questionAnswer['q1'] as $question => $questionID)
    <table class="question">
      <tr>
        <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
        <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
      </tr>
    </table>
    @endforeach

    @foreach($questionAnswer['q2'] as $question => $questionID)
    <table class="question">
      <tr>
        <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
        <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
      </tr>
    </table>
    @endforeach

    @foreach($questionAnswer['q3'] as $question => $questionID)
    <table class="question">
      <tr>
        <td class="labels"><p>User:</p></td>
        <td><p>&nbsp;{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}</p></td>
        <input type="hidden" name="question[]" value="{{ str_replace("<title>", "$q", $question) }}">
      </tr>
    </table>
    @endforeach

    @foreach($questionAnswer['intent'] as $intent => $intent)
    <input type="hidden" name="intent" value="{{$intent}}">
    @endforeach

    <input type="hidden" name="entityValue" value="{{$q}}" readonly/>

    <br><br>

    <div class="new-field">
      <table class="response">
        <tr>
          <td class="labels"><p>Answer:</p></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="newAnswer[]" value=""></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
<?php
  $number++;
?>

@endforeach
  </form>
</div>
```